# vector of points to line in MATLAB line(x,y) or dpsimplify(P,thresh)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, line

i want to draw a line from x and y vector of points , i wrote this codes in MATLAB

```
line(x,y)
```

or

```
dpsimplify(p,thresh)
```

but result is bad , because of the irregular connection between points ,for example one point in (30,20) coordinate linked to (100 , 21 ) , while there is a (31,21) beside this .

[image: the image]
<sub>(source: [picofile.com](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8217160118/Untitled.jpg))</sub>

how i can connect correct points to each other?
thank you .

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of vectors and explain how you want to connect them?

Comment: i also try plot(x,y) , but because of unsorted arrangement of points , lines became look like a above image .

Comment: points sorted by column or row but correct form of points is look like :
for example:  
x=1:10;
y=sin(x);
plot(x,y)
but my points :
x=[5 , 1 , 3 , 4 ]
y=[sin(5) , sin(1) , sin(3) , sin(4) ]

Answer (score -1):

thanks too all , solution is found :

```
n=1;
pt1=[data(n,1), data(n,2)];

figure
scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2),'r*')
hold on

for i=1:size(data,1); 
     if isempty(pt1)~=1;
[Liaa,Locbb] = ismember(pt1(:)',data,'rows');
     if Locbb~=0;
data(Locbb,:)=[];

[n,d] = knnsearch(data,pt1(:)','k',1);
x=[pt1(1,1) data(n,1)];
y=[pt1(1,2) data(n,2)];

pt1=[data(n,1), data(n,2)];

plot(x,y);

else
    end

     else
         end

end

hold off
```